# Tomcat 7 doesn´t start

Tags: java, tomcat, opensuse

I have a OpenSuse Linux, and I installed Tomcat 7.0.52, but when I run startup.sh, always is OK. I run nmap in localhost, but tomcat service and port doesn´t appear.

```
Starting Nmap 5.21 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2016-01-21 18:09 UYST 
Nmap scan report for localhost (127.0.0.1) Host is up (0.0000020s latency). 
Not shown: 991 closed ports PORT      
STATE SERVICE 
22/tcp    open  
ssh 23/tcp    open  
telnet 25/tcp    open  
smtp 53/tcp    open  
domain 111/tcp   open  
rpcbind 631/tcp   open  
ipp 2049/tcp  open  
nfs 3306/tcp  open  
mysql 10000/tcp open  snet-sensor-mgmt

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.08 seconds
```

When I run shutdown.sh, I recieve this message:

```
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.52
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.52
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /opt/java/jdk1.8.0._65/jre
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/opt/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.52/bin/catalina.sh: línea 437: /opt/java/jdk1.8.0._65/jre/bin/java: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

My environments variables:

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_65/

echo $JRE_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0._65/jre
```

What´s wrong ?

Comment: What makes you think something is wrong?  Do you have a firewall running? Are you running tomcat as a user?  The `nmap` only scanned 1000 ports, are you sure it attempted to scan the tomcat server port?

Comment: `jdk1.8.0._65` vs. `jdk1.8.0_65`

Comment: I'd use `netstat -ln` to list the open ports, just to be sure - like it has been pointed out, `nmap` only lists well-known services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could it be that you have a typo in your environment variable definitions?

```
echo $JAVA_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0_65/

echo $JRE_HOME
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0._65/jre
```

It seems like the latter, JRE_HOME, is being used and leads to the error condition latter on:

```
/opt/java/jdk1.8.0._65/jre/bin/java
```

Try redefining the JRE_HOME environment variable like this:

```
export JRE_HOME='/opt/java/jdk1.8.0._65/jre/bin/java'
```